# ASP.NET Core Url Rewrite

Tags: asp.net-core

We are trying to use the Url rewrite feature in ASP.NET Core, but it seems not to work.

The following is how we have coded in the `Startup` file in the `Configure` method:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
                  .AddRewrite(@"^restaurant/(\d+)", $"restaurant/hello", skipRemainingRules: true);


app.UseRewriter(options);   //enabled Rewriter
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
//app.UseDefaultFiles();
//app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseFileServer();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.UseRouting();
```

Are we doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your Url rewrite can work,you can try to add the following middleware after `app.UseStaticFiles();`:

```
app.Run(context => context.Response.WriteAsync(
        $"Rewritten Url: " +
        $"{context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString}"));
```

Your code will change the context.Request.Path from `restaurant/(\d+)` to `restaurant/hello`,when you add the middleware,you can see the change of  url directly.You can refer to the Url rewrite in the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-6.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware).Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I don't understand is why does the code I have written not work as per docs.

Comment: `What I don't understand is why does the code I have written not work as per docs. `,so you mean add a middieware,and the `context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString` will not  change?